# IntelliJ leap from Eclipse - where are my breadcrumbs

Tags: intellij-idea

I just switched from eclipse to IntelliJ 9.0 and it is wonderful.
The one thing I miss the most is the "Show breadcrumbs" line in Eclipse which shows me the method I am located in - in the class file.
The solution is obviously to write short methods, but I do need the "show breadcrumbs" feature from time to time.

Anyone knows if there is a similar feature in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View | Context Info** (Alt+Q in the default Windows keymap)

Comment: I tried this, but it only shows the current class, not the current method.

Comment: It will show current method signature if the method start doesn't fit the screen. I've just verified it with IDEA 9.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the structure panel with an "Auto-scroll from source" or show the "file structure popup" (in view).

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 now has [breadcrumbs for java files](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/06/intellij-idea-2016-2-eap-adds-breadcrumb-for-java/).

> To enable this feature, go to *Settings → Editor → General → Appearance*
>   and select *Show breadcrumbs*.

[image: breadcrumbs in idea]